# Torch hub, import model from private git repository

Tags: pytorch, nlp, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load a torch model from one of my private repositories, to google colab using the following code:

torch.hub.load("EliasLeijon/myRepoName", 'bart.base')

But I am getting the error HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found, which is not surprising since the repo is private.

Is there any way for me to access my private repository in this manner?

I have tried reading the documentation on torch.hub, but could not find anything related to private repositories.

I would be very grateful if anyone could explain how to do this or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clone your repository into your Google Colab notebook, and then load the model from there.

```
!git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
```

Then navigate to the directory where the model is located:

```
%cd REPO_NAME/directory/containing/model
```

Finally Load the model using torch.load() method:

```
model = torch.load('model_name.pth') where .pth is your model file.
```

Now try using it in your code `output = model(input)`

As a last step, delete the cloned repository once you finish working to avoid unnecessary storage costs.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. However, the repo seems to be way too large (about 40 Gigabytes) for this since the loading is taking forever.

Comment: You might try a different hosting service (e.g. Amazon S3) and then load it directly in Colab.  Also, can you use a smaller version of your model? Or, possibly, use a pre-traind model of the same architecture? Check `torch.hub` or Hugging Face model hub for that matter.